# CSS Grid to remove empty, unused space

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a nav-bar with the grid property in CSS. All I would like to do is remove empty grid space to make the design look nicer.

Here's what the design initially looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zwvc.png)

I wanted to make it responsive by using the following code:

```css
.nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .25em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.nav-child {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondary-flex nav">
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    Contact us
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    About us
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    Random
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    More text
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I resize the navbar it will dynamically drop a grid object down 1 row, but still keep the width of the grid object constant to the rest. Is there a way I can force the single grid object on the new row to span the width of the entire navbar when it's by itself? In other words, remove all empty space when a new row is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more suitable for flexbox than CSS-grid:

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.nav-child {
  min-width:200px;
  flex:1;
  margin:0.125em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondary-flex nav">
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    Contact us
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    About us
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    Random
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-flex nav-child">
    More text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! In my research I heard flexbox was mainly 1-dimensional but this definitely proves me wrong. Where did I hear that from??

Comment: @JackWright probably you understood the *1-dimensional* wrong ... flexbox is basically one direction (either column or row) but we can have wrapping so elements can go to next line or next column if there isn't enough space